# Where to unscrew this kitchen faucet

Tags: kitchens, faucet

I want to replace my kitchen faucet. Where should I remove it?
At the top (the green arrow) or the bottom (the red arrow)?

[image: Kitchen faucet]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend **BOTH**. You need to disconnect at the top (green arrow) to remove the existing faucet, but while you are at it you should disconnect those flex supply lines and replace them with high quality braided stainless steel flex lines.

[image]